# start_workspaces() only accepts keyword arguments

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-workspaces

I am trying to write a Python code in Lambda function which will start the stopped workspaces when the alarm triggers. The response type is dict.

But I am getting the error. Below is my code and error.

```py
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('workspaces')
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.describe_workspaces(
        DirectoryId='d-966714f114'
    )
        
    #print(response)
    
    print("hello")

    for i in response['Workspaces']:
        if(i['State']== 'STOPPED'):
            print(i['WorkspaceId'])
            client.start_workspaces(i['WorkspaceId'])
```

```json
{
    "errorMessage": "start_workspaces() only accepts keyword arguments.",
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 21, in lambda_handler\n    client.start_workspaces(i)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 354, in _api_call\n    raise TypeError(\n"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the call's [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/workspaces.html#WorkSpaces.Client.start_workspaces), it says that it expects keyword `StartWorkspaceRequests`, which is in itself a list of dicts:

```
{
    'WorkspaceId': 'string'
},
```

The call doesn't accept arguments (just a value being passed without corresponding keyword). You need to adapt your call to conform to the format expected by boto3.

```py
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('workspaces')
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.describe_workspaces(
        DirectoryId='d-966714f114'
    )
        
    workspaces_to_start = []
         
    for i in response['Workspaces']:
        if(i['State']== 'STOPPED'):
            workspaces_to_start.append({'WorkspaceId': i['WorkspaceId']})

    if workspaces_to_start:
        client.start_workspaces(StartWorkspaceRequests=workspaces_to_start)
```

Comment: Yes, I got your point. But is there any other way we can start the stopped workspaces as this lambda is a part of automation and passing values is not a feasible option. Thanks

Comment: I don't quite get it. Your question was specifically about this error. This follow up question makes no sense in context of the question and needs more info about your setup to be available

Comment: Apologies, if i were not clear with my follow up comment. I meant to say that with my code I am trying to start the workspaces which are in stopped state. But there is an error with the syntax and I am not sure how to proceed further since the code I am writing doesn’t work. So I am looking for a way, where the for-loop stores the value in the dict and then call the `start_workspaces` function.

Comment: I've added a code snippet which implements my suggestion, hope that will clarify things

Comment: This is awesome Oleksii. It worked. Thanks a lot!!